# What does <Props, State> mean in `React.Component<Props, State>`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript, and I trying to write React with Typescript.

I see a demo as below.

I'm confused about the `<Props, State>` in the class declaration. I think it is just **generic**, but this make no sense. Dose it has any relation with the `type Props` and `type State` above?

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  label: string;
};

type State = {
  count: number;
};

export class ClassCounter extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  readonly state: State = {
    count: 0,
  };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    const { handleIncrement } = this;
    const { label } = this.props;
    const { count } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          {label}: {count}
        </span>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrement}>
          {`Increment`}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "but this make no sense" why not?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't know why need a generic here? Why not just delete the `<Props, State>`?

Comment: The `<Props, State>` refers to the `Props` and `State` types just above and defines the structure of the props and state respectively.

Comment: @Chris Is it **generic**? How dose the `Props` and `State` types pass to the component? Sorry I couldn't find any explanation from typescript document

Comment: @BigLiao, no. Generic is usually symbolized with `<T>`. Anyway, these values aren't "passed" anywhere. Remember this is TypeScript. TS does not run on the client, it is only a developer tool. It basically helps you, the programmer, to know what the props are (When you use `ClassCounter` in a render somewhere, it will tell you what props it expects and their type). It will throw an error on build if you pass a "number" to the `label` prop, for example. Same for state.

Comment: @BigLiao with this code here `const { label } = this.props;`, `label` will be a `string` because of your `Props` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.Component<Props, State>` is the "passing in" you describe, this is not *declaring* generics (which has similar syntax).

It's the same relationship as `foo(x, y)` has to `function foo(x, y) {}`.

In the former, you're passing in the variables named `x` and `y` into the function `foo`.

In the latter, you're declaring a function `foo` that expects two variables to be passed in, and it going to refer to them inside the function as `x` and `y`.

Equivalently, `type React.Component<Props, State> =` would be declaring, and `class Xx extends React.Component<Props, State> {` is saying "here, use these types called `Props` and `State` that I've defined elsewhere".

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.

Comment: Can you accept / upvote the answer in that case @BigLiao

Comment: If I want a generic here, It should like this right?

`export class ClassCounter<T> extends React.Component<Props, State> {...}`